Is it safe to use a Blender Object as a Python dict key in a background bpy script?
From the Blender Gotchas page I know that Object references are invalidated on Undo/Redo, but what about background script execution where no Undo is performed? Can I safely use a bpy.types.Object instance as a dict key in such a scenario?
Example:
my_dict = {}
my_dict[bpy.data.objects["Cube"]] = "hello"

It always works for me and I hadn't any issues but is this reliable? I want to confirm whether I can continue this way.

This seems safe and does not invalidate the pointer when the user deletes/modifies the object. Except Undo/Redo
